# what are good resources to get the most out of csh or tsch?

Tags: linux, shell, csh, tcsh

I would like to get the most out of working in cch or tcsh shell.

I am looking for general tips (post them away), online tips, or book.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The csh or tcsh man page has pretty much everything you need to get started.  I'd read through that first.

This O'Reilly book is also a good resource:  http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565921320/